Using Stripe's PaymentElement to update cards
I am using Stripe's Payment Element to allow a user to add new cards. I am also using the API to get a list of all saved cards. Now, I was hoping I can use the Payment Element to edit the card data too.
In a standard payment element I can already edit my saved cards:


So basically, the only missing piece looks to be instructing the Payment Element that on load, it should automatically open the specific's payment method update screen. But as far as I can see, there are no options todo that.
Any ideas/alternatives?

Unclear from you ask, but it seems like you want the Payment Element to automatically load the update UI for a specific Payment Method when initialised? Can you please confirm?

Yes, this is correct.

Not supported today I'm afraid. Your customers would need to explicitly click into the card update functionality via the UI.
